# Trim doesn't remove \n

Tags: php

I am taking a string from textarea and exploding it and trimming each line of the array with array_map():

```
$answers = explode("\n", $data['answers']);
// remove all whitespace such as \r (carriage return)
$asnwers = array_map('trim', $answers);
```

Then I store each array value in a separate row in a table answers in the database. The problem is there seems to be \n character at the end of each answer in the database. When I echo answers in HTML like this:

```
<?php foreach ($this->answers as $a): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $this->escape($a->body); ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php endforreach; ?>
```

When I then look at the HTML source I see this:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>Some random answer
</td>
                </tr>
```

As you can see, there is a newline (probably \n) at the end of the string because the  closing tag gets moved to the next line.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to care what the HTML source looks like?

Comment: @Dolph Mathews: Would you not be uneasy about uneccessary line breaks in your database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$asnwers = array_map('trim', $answers);
```

You're assigning the return value of array_map to `$asnwers`. It should be `$answers`.

Comment: +1 That's also what i was thinking (although it could also just be a simple typo in the question)

Comment: Damn, how could I not see that.